# oracle hierarchical query by specifing root and leaf node

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an oracle table with following fields MgrID, EmpID, Name.

The Hierarchy actually starts at CEO level but I want to specify the EmpID of CIO as the root and EmpID of a particular employee and get the hierarchy for that employee. How do I build that query in Oracle?

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result; what have you tried so far and what problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

In orcale you can use a select with start with and connect by

```
 select  * from your_table  
 start with EmpID = yuor_value
 connect by prior your_child = your_parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_name (
  EmpID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  MgrID INT REFERENCES Table_name ( EmpID ),
  Name  VARCHAR2(10),
  Role  VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT 1, NULL, 'Amy',     'CEO'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1,    'Bob',     'Director' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1,    'Carol',   'Director' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2,    'Deb',     'CIO'      FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH role = 'CIO'
CONNECT BY PRIOR MgrID = EmpID;
```

**Output**:

```
     EMPID      MGRID NAME       ROLE     
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         4          2 Deb        CIO        
         2          1 Bob        Director   
         1            Amy        CEO
```